# TOR security in a static IP

Tags: tor, static-ip, restrictions

At my work place i am provided with a static IP. WHere in many of the important sites are blocked for various reasons. Will accessing those sites using Tor browser get detected on the main server....?

Comment: You should not be circumventing your work's filters. You may loose your job if you get caught.

Comment: If your boss (opps should be IT technicians) set up a hw firewall and blocks them, using proxy plus SSL can probably bypass it, but I'd say: **work hard**

Answer (score 5):

The destination will see traffic coming from a Tor exit node and not your static IP.

A list of Tor exit nodes is publicly available and therefore server operators can choose to block it, but it's fruitless to try to trace it back to origin.

If you meant if someone from your network or workplace could detect what sites you are visiting, if you are not also causing your DNS lookups to go through Tor, then your network's DNS server or any intermediate device could be logging those requests and know what sites you were trying to visit.

Comment: Also, having a dynamic address at home does not give you any more security than a static one. Your ISP will have logs that connect you to your IP at a point in time, so resetting your modem to get a new one won't hide your trail.